# If $(a_n)$ monotonous and not zero convergent then $(2^na_{2^n})$ is also not zero convergent

Tags: real-analysis

There was an excercise About condensed sums. We should prove that:

If $(a_n)$ is **monotonous** then $\sum_{n}a_n$ converges/diverges iff $\sum_{k}2^ka_{2^k}$ converges/diverges

Textbooksolution:

It is sufficient to look at a decreasing Zero convergent sequence $(a_n)$

$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k,v_n=\sum_{k=1}^n2^ka_{2^k}$

If $K,N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $2^{K-1}<N\leq 2^K$ then

$S_N\le S_{2^K}\leq a_1+v_{K-1}$ and

$S_N\ge S_{2^{K-1}}\geq a_1/2 +v_{k-1}/2$

I have understood that the partialsums are Always positive since every $a_n$ must be positive. And if the partialsums can be bounded then because the partialsums are monotonously rising the sequence of partialsums is converging to its Supremum. And $s_k$ is bounded if and only if $v_k$ is bounded.

Again because $a_n$ is decreasing and zeroconvergent the partialsums are always positive. If one cannot be boundet then also the other one cannot be bounded.

**My Question** is that in the excercise the Task was to Show that the Statement holds if $(a_n)$ is monotonous. But we have only looked at decreasing monotonous $(a_n)$ and what is more important we have assumed that $(a_n)$ is Zero convergent.

What if $(a_n)$ is not Zero convergent then $\sum_n a_n$ necessarily diverges.

But to prove the Statement we also have to Show that $\sum_n 2^na_{2^n}$ diverges. It would be sufficient in this case to Show that $(2^na_{2^n})$ is not Zero convergent.

How can I do that?

Comment: $2^na_{2^n}>a_{2^n}\geq\epsilon$

Comment: But even if the sequence converges to zero the sum may diverge. It seems unhelpful to consider the case where it doesn't converge to 0 separately.

Answer (score 1):

By changing $(a_n)$ to $(-a_n)$ we can reduce the proof to the case when $(a_n)$ is decreasing. If $\sum a_n$ is convergent the $ a_n \to 0$ and if $\sum 2^{k}a_{2^{k}}$ converges then $2^{k}a_{2^{k}} \to 0$. This implies $a_{2^{k}} \to 0$. By monotonicity this implies $a_k \to 0$. Hence in either direction we can assume that $a_n \to 0$.